# Status 400 sent from backend is not recognised as HttpResponse in the angular interceptor

Tags: node.js, angular, rxjs

I have http interceptor.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from "ngx-spinner";

@Injectable()
export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    @Inject('API_URL') private baseUrl: string,
    public router: Router,
    public toasterService: ToastrService,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
    // API url
    request = request.clone({ url: `${this.baseUrl}/${request.url}` });

    // notifications
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap(evt => {
        this.spinner.show();
        if (evt instanceof HttpResponse && evt.body && typeof evt.body.success != "undefined") {
          if(evt.body.success) {
            this.spinner.hide();
            this.toasterService.success(evt.body.message);
          } else {
            this.spinner.hide();
            this.toasterService.error(evt.body.message);
          }
        } else {
          this.spinner.hide();
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

there i am showing with toastr messages that are coming from backend, and if success is true then i show green toastr if false then red toastr indicating that something is wrong. And everything is good when the response status sent from nodejs backend api hosted on azure cloud is 200 ( the default one ).

```
context.res = {
            body: { success: false, message: `Please add title field` }
        };
```

The problem is if i send response with status 400 for example

```
context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: { success: false, message: `Please add title field` }
        };
```

then somehow the condition in mu http interceptor

evt instanceof HttpResponse

is not executed. But i don't know why. Why status code 400 is not instance of HttpReponse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return next.handle(req).pipe(
            tap(
                (res: any) => {// success block},
                (error: any) => {// error block}
            )
        );
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my app, you could probably achieve the same thing with the `filter` rxjs operator.

```js
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (error.status === 400) {
      // Do something
    }
  })
);
```